# How to use 'refs' while using withRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to call a method in the child component from the parent component the issue is child component is exported using **withRouter** so i'm unable to use 'ref'. I tried of 
 **export default withRouter(component,{ withRef: true });** 
But I didn't implement redux to use **getWrappedInstance()**   How could  I manage this??? Here's my code Parent component

```
 `triggerupdateCallback = () => { 
    this.refs.child.updateCallback();
   }
<Child ref="child"/>
```

`